# Reading logs of a deployed Google script

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to read the logs of published google apps script?

Presently I am able to get the logs using `Logger.log()` in debug mode.

But when we face certain issues with the script once its published, it becomes impossible to get to its cause.

Comment: I highly doubt it, as this would pose some serious privacy/security risks. Remote.Logger.log(//all spreadsheet data); - yikes.

Comment: @rGil any reasons for your for your concerns? I mean what security risks? And if thats the case, I wonder how do we get to the logs of a deployed web app, because without it, its almost impossible to get the cause of an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. Depending on the way it was executed, you can at most get to the last run log, it gets lost on the next script run log.
Make your own logger function, for example by doing appendRow on a spreadsheet. Ive done one that even logs the full stack trace per log, which is way better than the native logger.
This of course asssumes you are logging rare events as it will consume more quotas.
See here for sample code on logging the stacktrace and such (scroll to the middle):
http://plusfortrello.blogspot.com/2013/08/spent-for-trello-google-apps.html

Comment: "you can at most get to the last run log" so how do I get to that? I assume that by "last strun" we mean the latest trigger.

Comment: From the menu. But my point is that is not useful because it gets lost quickly

Comment: I dont think that is possible for a published google script. It may be possible to read the logs when we are editing the script via the menu.

Comment: thats why im suggesting the alternative and why i said "at most", depends how you execute it.

Comment: Hmm sounds good. I feel that google scripts dont have this feature of logging a published script.So remotely logging seems a justified solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is a debug object I use for logging and error checking. It always writes to Logger but also to a sheet called "log" in a linked spreadsheet. I've copied this from a script I'm working on (Flubaroo) so there may be a few external functions missing.

```
// debug.gas.gs
// ============
//
// Development/debug functions.

// TODO_AJR - Add function name as first parameter of logging functions

// TODO_AJR - Generally, should there be some indication to the user that,
// there has been an error when debug is turned off? Couldn't we try and 
// catch the errors further up rather than ignoring them in production and
// letting GAS catch them in debug.

// Unit Tests
// ==========

// testDebugClass()
// ----------------
//
// Unit tests for DebugClass(). Check log for results.

function testDebugClass()
{
  Debug.info("testDebugClass() - PASS - info test call");
  Debug.warning("testDebugClass() - PASS - warning test call");

  Debug.assert_w(false, "testDebugClass() - PASS - assert_w test call");  

  // This will test Debug.error().
  Debug.assert(true, "testDebugClass() - FAIL - Should not see this");

  Debug.info("testDebugClass() - All tests PASSED");

  return true;

} // testDebugClass()

// Debug Service
// =============

Debug = new DebugClass();

function DebugClass()
{
  this.debugOn = DEBUG_ON;
  this.loggingOn = LOGGING_ON;
  this.log_sheet;
  this.last_msg;

} // DebugClass()

// DebugClass.info()
// -----------------
//
// Output debug trace.

DebugClass.prototype.info = function(msg)
{
  Logger.log(msg);

  this.last_msg = msg;

  if (!this.loggingOn)
    {
      return;
    }

  if (typeof this.log_sheet === 'undefined')
    { 
      // Store log sheet name.

      this.log_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                                     .getSheetByName(LOG_SHEET_NAME);

      if (this.log_sheet === null)
        {
          // TODO_AJR - Could create it.
          // TODO_AJR - use langStr.

          Browser.msgBox(langstr("FLB_STR_NOTIFICATION"), 
                         "You need to create a sheet called " + 
                           LOG_SHEET_NAME + 
                           " with logging enabled", 
                         Browser.Buttons.OK);

          this.error("DebugClass.info() - no 'log' sheet");

          return;
        }
    }

  if (this.log_sheet === null)
    {
      // Attempted, but failed, to find the log sheet on a 
      // previous call to info().
      return;
    }

  // Add the trace message to the end of log sheet.

  var row = this.log_sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  var range = this.log_sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 2);
  var time = new Date();

  range.setValues([[time, msg]]);

} // DebugClass.info()

// DebugClass.warning()
// --------------------
//
// Output warning.

DebugClass.prototype.warning = function(msg)
{ 
  if (typeof msg !== "string")
    {
      this.error("DebugClass.warning() - incorrect parameter type");
    }

  this.info("WARNING - " + msg);

} // DebugClass.warning()

// DebugClass.error()
// ------------------
//
// Output error trace and throw an error (only this function
// should decide whether to throw the errors).

DebugClass.prototype.error = function(msg)
{ 
  if (typeof msg !== "string")
    {
      msg = "DebugClass.error() - parameter must be a string";

      this.info(msg);

      if (this.debugOn)
        {
          throw(msg);
        }
    }

  this.info("ERROR - " + msg);

  if (this.debugOn)
  {
    throw(msg);
  }

} // DebugClass.error()

// DebugClass.assert()
// -------------------
//
// Issue error if assertion false.

DebugClass.prototype.assert = function(assertion, msg) 
{ 
  if (typeof assertion !== "boolean")
    {
      assertion = false;
      msg = "DebugClass.assert() - first parameter must be a boolean";
    }
  else if (typeof msg !== 'string')
    {
      assertion = false;
      msg = "DebugClass.assert() - second parameter must be a string";
    }

  if (!assertion)
    {
      this.error(msg);
    }

} // DebugClass.assert()

// assert_w()
// ----------
//
// Issue warning if assertion false.

DebugClass.prototype.assert_w = function(assertion, msg) 
{ 
  if (typeof assertion !== 'boolean')
    {
      assertion = false;
      msg = "DebugClass.assert_w() - first parameter must be a boolean";
    }
  else if (typeof msg !== 'string')
    {
      assertion = false;
      msg = "DebugClass.assert_w() - second parameter must be a string";
    }

  if (!assertion)
    {
      this.warning(msg);
    }

} // DebugClass.assert_w()

// Event Handlers
// ==============

function debugMenu(menuEntries)
{
  if (Debug.debugOn)
    {
      // Line break.
      menuEntries.push(null);

      menuEntries.push({name: "Debug: Reset", functionName: "resetFlubaroo"});

      menuEntries.push({name: "Debug: Reinitialize", functionName: "reinitialize"});

      if (UI.isOn())
        {
          menuEntries.push({name: "Debug: Skip UI", functionName: "skipUIMenu"});
        }
      else
        {
          menuEntries.push({name: "Debug: Display UI", functionName: "displayUIMenu"});
        }

      menuEntries.push({name: "Debug: Clear Log", functionName: "logClear"});

      menuEntries.push({name: "Debug: Dump Config", functionName: "dumpConfig"});

      menuEntries.push({name: "Debug: Trigger Autograde", functionName: "onAutogradeSubmission"});

      menuEntries.push({name: "Debug: Run Tests", functionName: "runTests"});

      menuEntries.push({name: "Debug: Delete Grades", functionName: "deleteGradesSheet"});

      if (ScriptProperties.getProperty(SCRIPT_PROP_SKIP_EMAIL))
        {
          menuEntries.push({name: "Debug: Send Emails", functionName: "toggleEmailSending"});
        }
      else
        {
          menuEntries.push({name: "Debug: Skip Emailing", functionName: "toggleEmailSending"});
        }
    }

} // debugMenu()

// dumpConfig()
// ------------

function dumpConfig()
{  
  Debug.info("dumpConfig() - SCRIPT_PROP_NUM_GRADED_SUBM: " + 
             Number(ScriptProperties.getProperty(SCRIPT_PROP_NUM_GRADED_SUBM)));

  Debug.info("dumpConfig() - SCRIPT_PROP_EMPTY_SUBM_ROW_PTR: " + 
             Number(ScriptProperties.getProperty(SCRIPT_PROP_EMPTY_SUBM_ROW_PTR)));

} // dumpConfig()

// logClear()
// ----------

function logClear()
{
  Debug.info("logClear()");

  var log_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                                .getSheetByName(LOG_SHEET_NAME);

  if (log_sheet)
    {
      log_sheet.deleteRows(1, log_sheet.getMaxRows() - 1);
      log_sheet.insertRowsAfter(1, 5);
    }

} // logClear()

// reinitialize()
// --------------

function reinitialize()
{
  Debug.info("reinitialize()");

  ScriptProperties.deleteAllProperties();

  // Clear the triggers.  
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

  for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++)
    {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }

  // Simulate a re-installation.
  onInstall();

} // reinitialize()

// resetFlubaroo()
// ---------------

function resetFlubaroo()
{
  logClear();
  reinitialize();
  deleteGradesSheet();

} // resetFlubaroo()

// deleteGradesSheet()
// -------------------

function deleteGradesSheet()
{  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = getSheetWithGrades(ss);

  if (sheet)
    {
      ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
      ss.deleteActiveSheet();

      // To avoid a bug in which 'Grades' get deleted, but appears to
      // stick around, switch to another sheet after deleting it.
      // TODO_AJR: bug still exists sometimes.

      var switch_to_sheet = getSheetWithSubmissions(ss);
      ss.setActiveSheet(switch_to_sheet);
    }

} // deleteGradesSheet()

// toggleEmailSending()
// --------------------

function toggleEmailSending()
{
  if (ScriptProperties.getProperty(SCRIPT_PROP_SKIP_EMAIL))
    {
      ScriptProperties.deleteProperty(SCRIPT_PROP_SKIP_EMAIL);
    }
  else
    {
      ScriptProperties.setProperty(SCRIPT_PROP_SKIP_EMAIL, 'true');
    }

} // toggleEmailSending()
```

---

UPDATE (March 11 2015): I've since moved to using [BetterLog](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/betterlog) and my [own wrapper library for BetterLog](https://script.google.com/d/1ZDOUyPJ93AeeFavZRoCMDJ2V5hmnXoOgtwiff_0qIUU8gndta40HEC6L/edit?usp=sharing) that automatically adds function names to the debug trace (MqTFuiXcPtS5rVUZ_jC9Z4tnfWGfgtIUb).